# ubuntu 16.04.1 snap install conjure-up error

Tags: snap, conjure-up

I have just download and install Ubuntu  16.04 Desktop
then tried to install `conjure-up` to install `Openstack` in one machine & got following error message:

```
~$ sudo snap install conjure-up --classic --beta

error: cannot perform the following tasks:
- Run configure hook of "conjure-up" snap if present (
-----
+ lxd_bin=/usr/bin/lxd
+ lxc_bin=/usr/bin/lxc
++ which lxd
+ '[' '' = '' ']'
+ snap install lxd
+ lxd_bin=/snap/bin/lxd
+ lxc_bin=/snap/bin/lxc
++ /snap/bin/lxd --version
+ VERSION=2.8
+ dpkg --compare-versions 2.8 gt 2.2
+ grep -q trusty /etc/lsb-release
+ /snap/bin/lxc network show lxdbr0
+ /snap/bin/lxc network create lxdbr0 ipv4.address=10.0.8.1/24 ipv4.nat=true ipv6.address=none ipv6.nat=false
LXD socket not found; is LXD installed and running?
-----)
```

Is there anything need to be done before this installation?

Comment: Remoe the `--beta` and try without `sudo` as seen [here](http://conjure-up.io/)...

Comment: just according to instructions from https://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud/conjure-up

tried without sudo :

~$ snap install conjure-up --classic
error: access denied (try with sudo)

Comment: Ok now try with `sudo` but don't add `--beta`!

Comment: got another error:

~$ sudo snap install conjure-up --classic
error: cannot perform the following tasks:
- Run configure hook of "conjure-up" snap if present (
-----
+ lxd_bin=/usr/bin/lxd
+ lxc_bin=/usr/bin/lxc
++ which lxd
+ '[' '' = '' ']'
+ snap install lxd
+ lxd_bin=/snap/bin/lxd
+ lxc_bin=/snap/bin/lxc
++ /snap/bin/lxd --version
cat: /proc/self/attr/current: Permission denied
/snap/lxd/976/wrappers/lxd: 5: exec: aa-exec: Permission denied
+ VERSION=
-----)

Comment: Do you have `snap` properly installed?

Comment: ~$ snap --version
snap    2.22.2
snapd   2.22.2
series  16
ubuntu  16.04

Comment: Please do `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade && sudo apt dist-upgrade`...then try with `--beta` this time...

Comment: FWIW, I'm seeing the aa-exec permission denied error, tried without --beta and with --beta, no difference.

Comment: @LaiEddy Can you update your post to reflect the most recent error you wrote about in your comments?

Comment: Also there is a bug report on this lxd snap error here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/snapd/+bug/1657252

Comment: I have just reinstalled the host with following steps to avoid the errors:
1.sudo apt-get install snapd
2.sudo apt-get install lxd lxd-client
3.sudo snap install conjure-up --classic --beta
4.newgrp lxd
5.conjure-up openstack

if someone want to try fix the previous error I got, I can re-install another host for the testing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an interesting error can you do the following:

```
sudo snap remove lxd
sudo apt-get install lxd lxd-client
conjure-up
```

To me this looks like an issue with the LXD snap running on Xenial. If this works I'll get with the LXD guys to see what may be going wrong with that snap.

Comment: Thanks , after these steps, 
~$ conjure-up
The program 'conjure-up' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install conjure-up

and then I re-run "sudo snap install conjure-up --classic --beta" 
no more lxd errors

Answer (score 1):

I got the exact same error when i ran "sudo snap install conjure-up --classic". After reading this thread i was able to succeed

`openstackuser@ubuntu:~$ sudo snap remove lxd
openstackuser@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install lxd lxd-client
openstackuser@ubuntu:~$ conjure-up`

then i was prompted to install conjure-up

`openstackuser@ubuntu:~$ conjure-up
The program 'conjure-up' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install conjure-up`

Installed conjure-up package with below command

```
openstackuser@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt install conjure-up
```

Finally, installed without errors

```
openstackuser@ubuntu:~$ sudo snap install conjure-up --classic
conjure-up 2.1.0 from 'canonical' installed
```

Thanks

Comment: You have installed two versions of `conjure-up` - why?

Answer (score 0):

I was getting a similar error on Linux Mint:

```
$ sudo snap install conjure-up --classic --beta

error: cannot perform the following tasks:
- Run configure hook of "conjure-up" snap if present
```

I fixed it by installing, `selinux`, rebooting, and then installing `snapd`:

```
sudo apt-get install selinux
reboot
sudo apt-get install snapd
```

For more info, see [this issue](https://github.com/RocketChat/Rocket.Chat/issues/5458#issuecomment-277250112).

Comment: have you create an instance/image running on it?
I have conjure-up openstack installed on ubuntu 16.04 , but still failed to create my own instance/image for testing